# tile operation in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Can anyone explain numpy's tile function? I couldn't figure out from the examples given in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html

Answer (score 11):

It simply repeats the numbers of elements in an array. If you have an array, like so `[1,2,3]`, then `np.tile([1,2,3], 2)` will repeat the elements twice and make a new array. As explained by Thorsten, `np` always returns an array even if you give it a list. So explaining with some examples:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar = [1]
>>> np.tile(ar, 2)
array([1, 1])
>>> np.tile(ar, 3)
array([1, 1, 1])
>>> np.tile(ar, 4)
array([1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> new_ar = [1,2,3]
>>> np.tile(new_ar, 2)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
>>> np.tile(new_ar, 3)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
#     |   1st |  2nd   |  3rd   | -> Repeats shown.
```

Comment: As your example show, tile (like most numpy functions) returns an array and not list, even if the input was a list.

Comment: @ThorstenKranz Yes, it does. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: >>> np.tile(a, (2, 2))
    array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
>>> np.tile(a, (2, 1, 2))
array([[[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
       [[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]])                                                     What does  np.tile(a, (2, 2)) and np.tile(a, (2, 1, 2)) do?

Comment: @PavanRavishankar Why don't you try it out on IDLE or python, and see what happens.

Comment: I did try.But I am not able to understand why the output for np.tile([0,1,2],(2,2)) is array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]).I am not able to interpret the result.

Comment: @PavanRavishankar Well the first 2 in `(2,2)` is both how many repetitions you wan't inside a an array itself. The second is for how many copies of the array you want. Hence, the same array is repeated twice.